Join two different networks together with a router
Two physically separated networks, one is 10.100.11.x, and other is 192.168.50.x, how can i use a router to physically joining them together in order for them to communicate with each other? What configuration should be made as well? Many thanks in advance.

Do you already have a specific kind of router, or only planning so far?

If no firewalling is needed between the two, add both interfaces to the same firewall zone and ensure Input, Output, and Forwarding are all set to enable for the firewall zone. If firewalling is required, put them in different firewall zones, enable Forwarding on both zones, and configure the requisite firewall rules needed for the specific traffic to be allowed. Either way, for anyone to provide an actual answer, the router make and model, as well as whether it’s using OEM firmware or open source firmware, would be required.
